# Dll function declaration and implementation are not linked

Tags: c++, dll

I'm trying to create a .dll and .lib files with VS2019 using this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=vs-2019) and load my library statically and dynamically.
I have dll project named dllSolution.
In my dllSolution there are standart framework.h, pch.h, dllmain.cpp, pch.cpp and my a.h file:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef DLLSOLUTION_EXPORTS
#define DLLSOLUTION_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLLSOLUTION_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif  // !DLLSOLUTION_EXPORTS

#ifndef WINAPI
#define WINAPI __stdcall
#endif  // !WINAPI

extern "C" DLLSOLUTION_API int WINAPI a();
```

with a.cpp:

```
#include "a.h"
#include "pch.h"

#ifndef WINAPI
#define WINAPI __stdcall
#endif  // !WINAPI

int WINAPI a() { return 10; }
```

but when I build this project it produces no .lib file as if there is no export from library:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: dllSolution, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>pch.cpp
1>a.cpp
1>dllmain.cpp
1>Generating Code...
1>dllSolution.vcxproj -> C:\CoolPathToMyDll\dllSolution\Debug\dllSolution.dll
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I have tried to move implementation into dllmain.cpp with no result.
I also have tried to switch ConfigurationType to StaticLibrary(.lib) and fine, it generates .lib, but then, when I statically link my library to another project and use this a() in my main(), it says:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__a@0 referenced in function _main
```

What is the problem and why does this problem happen?

Comment: The #include for pch.h must be first.  As-is it skips the #include for a.h (note the warning you got for that), so the compiler doesn't know you tried to export it.

Comment: @HansPassant, thanks, placing pch.h at the top of includes solved the problem. Can you give a bit more explanation of the situation(why does including pch skips includes before? any documantation for that?)? Btw, I didn't get any any warnings for including a.h before pch.h.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4627?view=vs-2019  It is supposed to be elevated to a fatal C1010 error in VS2017 and up, VS2019 has too many agile bugs to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @HansPassant admitted, the problem is

> The #include for pch.h must be first. As-is it skips the #include for a.h (note the warning you got for that), so the compiler doesn't know you tried to export it.

Placing any includes before pch.h results in [warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4627?view=vs-2019) in VS2017, but not in VS2019 (at the time of asking the question).

Reason of this behavior is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54121917/what-is-pch-h-and-why-is-it-needed-to-be-included-as-the-first-header-file) (short version) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/creating-precompiled-header-files?view=vs-2019) (long version).

Hope this answer will help someone to save hours of useless changing linking options.