# Compiler doesn't see the C++11 identifiers

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, googletest

When I was trying to build the Google test c++ project I caught the errors

```
Error   C3861   't1': identifier not found
Error   C2065   't1': undeclared identifier
Error   C2039   'thread': is not a member of 'std'
Error   C2065   'thread': undeclared identifier
Error   C2146   syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 't1'
```

My test code is:

```
#include <future>
#include <thread>

#include "pch.h"
TEST(...)
{
    // preconditions here

    std::thread t1([&] {
        Sleep(100);
        testee.enqueue(item);
        });
    
    t1.join();
    
    // other logic
}
```

Why I cannot use the std::thread and other C++11 features in my project? How can I do it?

Comment: Did you `#include <thread>`? Which version of visual studio? Which compiler flags?

Comment: @mch yes, I did `#include <thread>`. I use Visual studio 2017. Where I may see the compiler flags in the VS 2017?

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles, hope I edited as you want

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 supports C++14 (default) or C++17 standards. It doesn't support older standards, so `<thread>` is for sure known. As @273K answered, the problem is caused by the precompiled header.

Comment: If you `#include <thread>` in several files in your project, then it is probably best to  `#include <thread>` inside `pch.h`. That probably decreases total build time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#include "pch.h"` must be first. Other #include directive prior `#include "pch.h"` are ignored.

Comment: Indeed. **Everything** before `#include "pch.h"` is simply ignored by MSVC compiler (with `/Yu"pch.h"` compiler option). That includes `#include`, `#define`, class declaration, and even syntax errors like random text! I got caught a few times with that, so I am now enforcing with a Git hook that every `.cpp` begins with `#include "pch.h"`.

Comment: Nice comment! I have never experienced such troubles because I have never added code before #include. You are welcome to modify my answer or add your own one.

Answer (score 0):

> Why I cannot use the std::thread and other C++11 features in my project?

Potential reason 1: You cannot use C++11 features unless you use C++11 or a later standard.

Potential reason 2: You cannot use `std::thread` unless you include the header that defines `std::thread`. It's defined in the header `<thread>`.

Comment: How to ensure that I use C++11 or a later standard?

Comment: @FooBoy Depends on what compiler you use. Consult the manual of the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding pch.h, you could refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54121917/what-is-pch-h-and-why-is-it-needed-to-be-included-as-the-first-header-file). I tested the code you uploaded in VS2019, and there was no error in the code. The result is shown in the picture.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include<Windows.h>
int main()
{
    std::thread t1([&] {
        Sleep(1000);
        });

    t1.join();
}
```

[image]

Regarding the use of C++11, you could set it in the project properties>configuration properties>general>C++ Languae Standard. I suggest you use C++14, because C++14 already contains the features of C++11.

[image]