# C++: cannot open source file "pch.h"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, precompiled-headers, pch

I'm using Visual Studio 2022, and trying to use precompiled headers. In my project settings under all configurations I have:

```
Precompiled Header:              Use (/Yu)
Precompiled Header File:         pch.h
Precompiled Header Output Fille: $(IntDir)$(TargetName).pch
```

In the properties of the `pch.cpp` file, I have the following settings:

```
Precompiled Header:             Create (/Yc)
Precompiled Header File:        pch.h
Precompiled Header Output File: $(IntDir)$TargetName).pch
```

My project compiles just fine, but I get a squiggly line under the `#include "pch.h"` in every file, except for `main.cpp` which is in the same directory as the `pch.h` file. I right-clicked the `pch.h` file and pressed `Exclude from project` but the problem persists.

If I remove the `#include "pch.h"` from the beginning of a file, I get a new error: `Precompiled header must be included at the top of source file`.

`pch.cpp`:

```
#include "pch.h"
```

`pch.h`:

```
#pragma once

[... std includes ...]

#include "Mineclone/Debug/Log.h"
#include "Mineclone/Debug/Assert.h"
```

[My project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hepo.png)

I am using C++20 and IntelliJ ReSharper C++

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And if you need to improve your question with details, then please **[edit]** it instead of writing comments.

Comment: I do have the file and it does get included when compiling and running. The problem is that the intelisense breaks when using a pch

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is "pch.h" and why is it needed to be included as the first header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54121917/what-is-pch-h-and-why-is-it-needed-to-be-included-as-the-first-header-file)

Comment: Is your include folders list configured to contain the "src" subfolder? See Project Property Pages → Configuration Properties → C/C++ → General → Additional Include Directories. Otherwise, the `#include "pch.h"` will not find the file because the "src" subfolder won't be considered. Also, do not exclude the "pch.h" from your project (because that file is also part of the project).

Comment: I think this is likely an issue with IntelliSense and the VS cache. Plenty of details/info in the question. I just either ignore or disable that wretched tool.