# Wrap c++ static library (.lib) functions into a DLL - dllexport

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, dllexport

I have a static library file (.lib) called `SampleArithmetic.lib` and the header file for it `SampleArithmetic.h`. Now using these files, I want to generate a DLL files for the functions present in the `SampleArithmetic.lib`.

**What I did:**

- Created a new project in VS2022 of type `Class Library`
- Configured include folder path (to access `SampleArithmetic.h`)
- Configured lib path and the lib required (i.e. `SampleArithmetic.lib`)
- and finally, added the code below in a .cpp file called `SampleArithmeticDLLGenerator.cpp`

  ```
    #include "SampleArithmetic.h"
    #include "pch.h"

    extern "C" {
        __declspec(dllexport) int add(int a, int b)
        {
            SampleArithmetic obj;
            return obj.Add(a, b);
        }

        __declspec(dllexport) int subtract(int a, int b)
        {
            SampleArithmetic obj;
            return obj.Subtract(a, b);
        }

        __declspec(dllexport) int multiply(int a, int b)
        {
            SampleArithmetic obj;
            return obj.Multiply(a, b);
        }
    }
  ```

**PROBLEM:**

I am getting the following errors:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   C2065   'SampleArithmetic': undeclared identifier   CPlusPlusDLLWrapper C:\Users\Downloads\TestProject\TestCppLibIntegrationInCSharp\CPlusPlusDLLWrapper\SampleArithmeticDLLGenerator.cpp   7

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   C2065   'obj': undeclared identifier    CPlusPlusDLLWrapper C:\Users\Downloads\TestProject\TestCppLibIntegrationInCSharp\CPlusPlusDLLWrapper\SampleArithmeticDLLGenerator.cpp   7

Comment: Not  exactly matching the error messages, but anything included *before* `pch.h` will be ignored by the compiler. (It assumes that part to be precompiled too).

Comment: @BoP: And that was exactly the issue. It resolved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is "pch.h" and why is it needed to be included as the first header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54121917/what-is-pch-h-and-why-is-it-needed-to-be-included-as-the-first-header-file)

Comment: @BoP Consider converting the  comment in to an answer.